# ARC error : cannot capture __autoreleasing variable in a block

Tags: ios, iphone, automatic-ref-counting, block, autorelease

I am trying to convert an old non-ARC project to ARC and I am getting this compilation error:
"cannot capture __autoreleasing variable in a block"

```
- (void)animateViewController:(__autoreleasing animatingViewController *)viewController 
{
   //[[viewController retain] autorelease]; // I replaced this with __autoreleasing

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.14 animations:^{
            [[viewController view] setAlpha:0.0];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [viewController.view removeFromSuperView];
        }];
}
```

Comment: That's a misuse of `_autoreleasing`. Don't "replace" what you had with anything (what you had was nutty too).

Comment: So why did you add the `__autoreleasing`?

Comment: @matt I know but whats equivalent of retain & autorelease

Comment: @matt I know what ARC does , I am trying to figure out whats wrong with this approach.

Comment: @matt again I want to know whats wrong with I am doing. I know whats right way. There are many questions on SO which tells me the same answer.

Comment: Actually, the retain-autorelease dance was redundant even before ARC.

Comment: @matt these comments could be more constructive. ARC and memory management in general are complex topics.

Comment: @Sean I will remove the other comments, but my first comment was spot on and pinpointed the source of the issue so I will leave it if you don't mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the block captures and retains the `viewController` parameter, it's not necessary to retain-autorelease the object. The lifetime is extended until the animation finishes because the completion block holds on to the controller.

Just remove the `__autoreleasing` specifier.

If, in another scenario, you **really have to** retain-autorelease an instance, you could assign it to an `id __autoreleasing __attribute__((unused))` local variable. But this should be a very uncommon case and might be a sign of a flaw in your design.

Comment: And also because ARC retains and autoreleases the incoming parameter in any case.

Comment: @Nikolai but  whats wrong with using __autoreleasing ? Its equivalent to what I have been doing.

Comment: @matt That's wrong. It retains and releases `__strong` parameters (sometimes).

Comment: @KunalBalani It's not wrong but prohibits the block capturing the controller (as the compiler complains).

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe so If I wasn't using block, then Its ok to use _autoreleasing in that case !

Comment: @KunalBalani **If** you want to extend the lifetime of the controller, yes. Normally, you don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

`__autoreleasing` is almost never used. `__autoreleasing` is mainly only important in a "pointer to `__autoreleasing`", i.e. `id __autoreleasing *`, or `NSString * __autoreleasing *`. In that case, it is different from "pointer to `__strong`", i.e. `id *`.

In your case, you have an `__autoreleasing` local variable directly. There is no benefit of this over `__strong` (if you don't put any qualifier, it is implicitly `__strong`), and is in fact worse. `__strong` will retain and release correctly as needed; not needing to use autorelease if there is no need.

Comment: The original (non ARC) code contained the line `[[viewController retain] autorelease];`. Somebody wanted to make sure the controller stays around longer than the scope of the current method. I don't know if this was really necessary but if it was it would not change with ARC. Using an `__autoreleasing` local variable would restore this behavior.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: That would still only guarantee it exists until just after the return of this method, and no more than that, since the calling method could potentially have an autorelease block around the call to this method. That's basically the same as what you get with `__strong`.

Comment: Right, from the point of view of the method implementation that's correct. Yet, the original developer probably knew who called the method and when and that there was only the runloop's pool in place and that did the job. I agree that it's poor design to rely on that.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: It appears from the ARC specification (http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#unretained-return-values) that if you mark the method as `__attribute__((ns_returns_autoreleased))`, the returned object should be guaranteed to be valid for the duration of the innermost autorelease pool.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to disable ARC for individual files by adding the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag for those files.

You add compiler flags in Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources. You have to double click on the right column of the row under Compiler Flags. You can also add it to multiple files by holding the cmd button to select the files and then pressing enter to bring up the flag edit box.